# R caret: difference between train and rfe

Tags: r, r-caret, rfe

since there are some methods available in the caret-ml that [don't have a built in feature selection](http://topepo.github.io/caret/featureselection.html), I was experimenting with `rfe`.

**Can somebody explain, what the difference between** `train()` and `rfe()` is - aside from training time and a ranked feature list? Are things only `train()` can do and vice versa?

Here is my example to illustrate the issue:

```
# worker functions
useRFE <- function(trainctrl) {
    control <- rfeControl(functions=caretFuncs, 
    method="cv", 
    repeats=5, 
    number=5, 
    returnResamp="final", 
    verbose = TRUE)


 # run the RFE algorithm
 resultsRFE <-
    rfe(
       training[,1:ncol(iris) - 1], 
       training$Species, 
       sizes = subsets, 
       rfeControl = control,
       method = "svmRadial",
       metric = "Accuracy",
       trControl = trainctrl
    )

  # test
  predictedClasses <- predict(resultsRFE, testing)
  confmat <- confusionMatrix(data = predictedClasses$pred, reference = testing$Species)
  confmat
  # Balanced Accuracy = 100%
}

useTrain <-  function(trainctrl) {      
  # train
  resultsTrain <- train(
       Species ~ .,
       data = training,
       method = "svmRadial",
       metric = "Accuracy",
       trControl = trainctrl
  )

  # test
  predictedClasses <- predict(resultsTrain, testing)
  confmat <- confusionMatrix(data = predictedClasses, 
       reference = testing$Species)
  confmat
  # Balanced Accuracy = 100%
}
# load library
library(caret)

# load iris data
data(iris)

# create datasets
inTrain <- createDataPartition(y = iris$Species,
    p = .75,
    list = FALSE)

## The output is a set of integers for the rows of Sonar
## that belong in the training set.
training <<- iris[ inTrain,]
testing <<- iris[-inTrain,]

# select count of features
subsets <- c(1:ncol(iris)-1)

# set controls
trainctrl <- trainControl(
    classProbs= TRUE, 
    method="cv", 
    repeats=5, 
    number=5, 
    verbose = TRUE)

# compare
ptm <- proc.time()
useTrain(trainctrl = trainctrl)
proc.time() - ptm
# Accuracy : 0.9167    
# User      System     passed 
# 1.54      0.06       10.27

ptm <- proc.time()
useRFE(trainctrl = trainctrl)
proc.time() - ptm
# Accuracy : 0.9167
# User      System     passed 
# 0.86      0.04       24.44
```

Comment: What is `useTrain` function?

Comment: please see the second snippet, where the two functions `useTrain()` and `useRFE ()` are defined :) Sorry for the long question, but I wanted to give all the code that is necessary to run it.

Comment: Better to define these functions before, as people tend to load example in order.

Answer (score 1):

`train` [builds and tunes](http://topepo.github.io/caret/TrainAlgo.png) a more with all the predictors as inputs. `rfe` does recursive feature elimination where [different predictors are removed](http://topepo.github.io/caret/Algo1.png) in a way that tries to optimize model performance. You can think of `rfe` as a possible wrapper around `train`.

Explanations of these approaches are on the [website](http://topepo.github.io/caret).

Comment: Does it make sense to run rfe() first for variable elimination, and then run train() for modeling?